# MVC4 should i use HttpUtility for validating input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wonder should i validate inputs.

Allways i'm not put the `ValidateInput` attribute beacause default Framework handle this so should i add some extra security like `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode input values.

Is there any vulnerability my way?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining data annotation validator, it is rendering from there.

Comment: Can you more explain please didn't understand.

Comment: Thank you for this, but i am already using DataAnnotations to validate model i'm asking default is solution for validate inputs beacase if you add some html script tag to any input you see "potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client"

Comment: You need to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` in web.config

Comment: Sur i am using MVC, MVC Framework already do that? I think you did not understand my question or i didn't explain